# Starting Gmail greasemonkey sample

Tags: javascript, gmail, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a Gmail Greasemonkey script and am getting an error message with the code below. I copied it from a sample script.

Error message is not helpful.

If I comment out the unsafeWindow.gmonkey.load() call - then there's no error message.

I have greasemonkey installed properly.

```html
window.addEventListener( 'load', function()
{
 if ( unsafeWindow.gmonkey )
  unsafeWindow.gmonkey.load( '1.0', init );

}, true );

function init(g)
{
 console.log("A");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following line in the script header

// @grant       GM_log

Once I changed GM_log to none - the script run w/o error.